# Reload render function after componentDidMount is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-class-based-component

I am trying to load ecwid store on my react.js website.
I have created a class component where there is a function called load ecwid.
I have put the function in the `componentDidMount()`.
The console logs tell me the function is loaded well and good. However, nothing shows up on the screen unless I manually refresh the page.

The following is my code:

```js
class EcwidStore extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
  };

  loadEcwid = () => {
    var isEcwidPage = document.getElementById('productBrowser') != null;
    if (window.ecwidLoaded && isEcwidPage) return;

    window.ecwidLoaded = true;
    window.ecwid_script_defer = true;
    window.ecwid_dynamic_widgets = true;

    window.ec.storefront = window.ec.storefront || Object();
    window.ec.enable_catalog_on_one_page = true;
    window._xnext_initialization_scripts = [
      {
        widgetType: 'ProductBrowser',
        id: 'my-store-xxx',
        arg: ['id=productBrowser', 'views=grid(20,3)'],
      },
      {
        widgetType: 'CategoriesV2',
        id: 'my-categories-xxx',
        arg: ['id=categoriesV2'],
      },
      {
        widgetType: 'SearchWidget',
        id: 'my-search-xxx',
        arg: ['id=searchWidget'],
      },
    ];

    if (typeof Ecwid != 'undefined') {
    } else {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.charset = 'utf-8';
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.id = 'ecwid-script';
      script.src = 'https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?xxx&data_platform=code&data_date=2021-01-14';
      document.getElementById('my-store-xxx').appendChild(script);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadEcwid();
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    console.log('loaded!');
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="my-search-xxx" />
        <div id="my-store-xxx" />
        <div id="productBrowser" />
        <div id="my-categories-xxx" />
        <div className="ec-cart-widget" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(EcwidStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to call your `render()` method from within `componentDidMount()`, your component shoud be rerendered upon state update. As such, maybe try removing your `this.render()` call from `componentDidMount()` and use `setState`at the end of your `loadEdwic` method.

Using component update method such as `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` might help you during your debugging process as well.

Comment: I had put that function cause I wanted the html to run after the function is loaded. Removing the this.render function is not making any difference to the output. I have already tried the state method